# how to define a global variable to be used in a function of an imported file?

Tags: python

Given two files A.py and B.py, A imports B.py and calls a function 'foo' defined in it. If 'foo' requires a global variable to keep track of itself, how and where should it be defined?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `B.py`, since this is the global scope for `foo()`:

```
var = 0

def foo():
    global var
    #use var here
```

But if `foo()` needs a variable to keep track of something, it should probably be a method in a class (a function with a state is not really a function).

Another solution is to add a `foo.var` variable:

```
def foo():
    'use foo.var here'
    # things

foo.var = 0
```

Depending on your intentions, it may be the case that what you are looking for is not a function but a [generator function](http://www.jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/04/07/improve-your-python-yield-and-generators-explained/).

Comment: I have tried that but for some reason I am getting "NameError: global name 'my_var' is not defined", is that possible?

Comment: only if you call `foo()` before making an actual assignment to the variable. I'll add an example

Comment: btw I know that from a software design this is incorrect and refactoring this method to a class is on the todo list :)

Comment: when you issue `import`, the body of the module will run.

Comment: BTW if my_var is a dictionary then initializing it with {} is sufficient? could that be the reason why for some variables an error is thrown?

Comment: it is sufficient, as long as you know lookups will result in an exception until you'll add a matching key-value pair.

Comment: Yep, had to assign at least one value to the dict for this to work. Toda :)